# JBPM. It is possible to correctly restore the task from status "Exited" to "Reserved" or "InProgress"?

Tags: jbpm

We use `jbpm 6.5.0.Final`. It is possible to correctly restore the task from status `Exited` to `Reserved` or `InProgress`?

[image]

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include source code formatted or directly the image instead of links. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to restart/restore completed or exited task. If you want to regenerate particular humantask then make use of gateway.